# Sharing Data Between Components using @Input

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components

I am new in Angular and I have tried using options available but i stuck at how to share data using an templateUrl from parent following is code snippet

header.component.html code

```
<header><label>{{childMessage}}</label></header>
```

-- header.component.ts file code

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input  } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import{AppComponent} from '../app.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css'],

})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childMessage: String;
 //@ViewChild(AppComponent,{static:false}) child;

}
```

--header.component.html code

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <label>{{  childMessage }}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

--app.component.html code

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div *ngIf="IsLogin==0" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 10%;">
<h1>App component html code is here </h1>   <
</div>
```

--Up to now for me okay problem starts in below code snippet that how should I pass childMessage to header.component.ts
examples or solutions i seen on internet was in template : ''
but this one is not used in my scenario or there will be different way to share data from parent to child
--app.component.ts code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

export class AppComponent  {
childMessage: string ="message from app component";

}
```

please help me get out of this here I am new in Angular

Answer (score 1):

```
<app-header [childMessage]="childMessage"></app-header>
<div *ngIf="IsLogin==0" style="text-align: center;padding-top: 10%;">
<h1>App component html code is here </h1>   <
</div>
```

try this

Comment: @AnantDoshi please refer to this topic - [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with your code is you have initialized the string `childMessage` in your child component to **String** which is not a declaration type in typescript. The right way is using lowercase as `string`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass data from your parent to child using property binding as stated below in your child component tag-

```
<app-header [childMessage]="childMessage"></app-header>
```